# Best way to exclude traffic from homepage to app?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-filters

I need to set up a filter (or segment) that excludes web app traffic.

On our site we have a button on the top right that takes the visitor to portal.domain.com which is where the web app is hosted.

I need a GA view that shows me traffic in which they have not clicked this button and gone on to use the web app.

Whats the best way of setting this up?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Add a filter to exclude, `campaign source` and set it to your domain. That will remove hits in the view that came from that URL.

Comment: Thanks. Im trying to exclude hits that go to URL not come from a URL.

Comment: Based on your question it sounds like you're trying to show web-app traffic that hasn't originated from the homepage button. Can you clarify? Because if you want to exclude hits to the web-app then you can modify the filter to exclude hostname `portal.domain.com`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to read the traffic that you want using a filter.

Is that page tracked by the same GA Account? If so, you set the filter to have a condition that excludes that page (although you'd probably identify it using its hostname, and you'd also have to be careful about cookie domains).

[image]

Alternatively, you could throw an event that triggers when people depart for that page, and then use that in the segment above.